# How do you integrate Phaser 3 to Ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, phaser-framework

I was wondering if you could provide pointers about how to integrate Phaser 3 into ionic 4. I read through some of the blogs and posts but they all seem to be dated or I am missing something obvious as I am a new to all this.

Also, if you have experience in this area, is this a recommended path ie wrapping phaser with ionic? Or would you recommend another way?

Many thanks,

Doug

I included the phaser.js to index.html by

```
<script src="assets/phaser/phaser.js"></script>
```

and tried to get access to Phaser at home.page.ts by

```
declare let Phaser;
```

However, I get "Cannot get namespace Phaser" error. I believe I need to include at the top of home.page.ts

```
/// <reference path=”phaser.d.ts”/>
```

But that throws

```
invalid reference directive syntax
```

I believe the reference syntax require "typescript 3.5.1" but not sure about the implications of upgrading regarding ionic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That snippet that you have posted looks like you have some smart quotes.

Is that what is in your actual code?

You should have it with clean double quotes like this:

```
/// <reference path="phaser.d.ts"/>
```